# float:right with correct semantics

Tags: html, css

I have the following html/css:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
#text {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
#subcontent {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="subcontent">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/50/50/1" width="50">
  </div>
  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In quis leo sapien. Nunc convallis elit purus, non fringilla quam lobortis at. Integer pharetra auctor luctus. In congue dolor a pretium facilisis. Donec et risus lacinia augue pellentesque mollis
    eget a urna. Sed dapibus est enim, id iaculis arcu ultrices sit amet. Donec quis dolor risus. Suspendisse a nunc a enim mattis finibus eget vitae diam. Phasellus dictum commodo metus, ut rutrum dolor pretium a. Aliquam at sem vel tortor mollis tristique.
    Proin neque dolor, pellentesque ut euismod id, finibus sed lacus. Mauris varius tempor diam, at varius risus. Etiam dictum metus et augue bibendum commodo. Vestibulum imperdiet elit vitae bibendum finibus. Maecenas mollis dui ex, id suscipit mauris
    cursus vitae. Vivamus nec faucibus elit.</div>
</div>
```

This is achieving the desired effect of making the text stay left and the sub content stay right, without having to specify a width for the text (for responsive behaviour). However, semantically this is incorrect as I have had to place `<div id="subcontent"/>` before `<div id="text"/>` in the html, even though the text should appear before the sub content (assuming reading rtl). I can live with this to get the job done but unfortunately when the screen size is very small I need to make `<div id="text"/>` full width and let the sub content flow naturally afterwards. This currently means the sub content is at the top and I need it to be at the bottom.

How can I change the css so that when the html is ordered

```
<div id="text"/>
<div id="subcontent"/>
```

the sub content will float right without being pushed down by the text?

I need to support IE9+

Comment: I realise this is ridiculously long-winded and difficult to understand so anyone who can word it better feel free to edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool. If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to change the order of the HTML, yet have the output still look the same?

If this is the case, you need to give `#text` AND `#subcontent` a `float:left;` add a clearing div and use a `calc` width on your text to make sure that the image will always fit in whilst the text can be responsively sized.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hk9ntyd2/1/

And here's the code:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

#text {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#subcontent {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In quis leo sapien. Nunc convallis elit purus, non fringilla quam lobortis at. Integer pharetra auctor luctus. In congue dolor a pretium facilisis. Donec et risus lacinia augue pellentesque mollis
    eget a urna. Sed dapibus est enim, id iaculis arcu ultrices sit amet. Donec quis dolor risus. Suspendisse a nunc a enim mattis finibus eget vitae diam. Phasellus dictum commodo metus, ut rutrum dolor pretium a. Aliquam at sem vel tortor mollis tristique.
    Proin neque dolor, pellentesque ut euismod id, finibus sed lacus. Mauris varius tempor diam, at varius risus. Etiam dictum metus et augue bibendum commodo. Vestibulum imperdiet elit vitae bibendum finibus. Maecenas mollis dui ex, id suscipit mauris
    cursus vitae. Vivamus nec faucibus elit.</div>
  <div id="subcontent">
    <img src="http://moviesalbum.com/wp-content/themes/sunny/timthumb.php?src=http://moviesalbum.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Koala-300x225.jpg&h=120&w=120&zc=1&q=90" width="50">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The `margin-left:50px;` solution should have worked fine, I personally find that the `calc` solution is a little neater, but feel free to use margin instead :)

Comment: `calc` is a great solution for IE9+. I'd forgotten about it as I've needed to support IE8 until very recently 

Comment: I'm glad to hear you don't have to support IE8 anymore :) You must be very relieved!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
#text {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
#subcontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In quis leo sapien. Nunc convallis elit purus, non fringilla quam lobortis at. Integer pharetra auctor luctus. In congue dolor a pretium facilisis. Donec et risus lacinia augue pellentesque mollis
    eget a urna. Sed dapibus est enim, id iaculis arcu ultrices sit amet. Donec quis dolor risus. Suspendisse a nunc a enim mattis finibus eget vitae diam. Phasellus dictum commodo metus, ut rutrum dolor pretium a. Aliquam at sem vel tortor mollis tristique.
    Proin neque dolor, pellentesque ut euismod id, finibus sed lacus. Mauris varius tempor diam, at varius risus. Etiam dictum metus et augue bibendum commodo. Vestibulum imperdiet elit vitae bibendum finibus. Maecenas mollis dui ex, id suscipit mauris
    cursus vitae. Vivamus nec faucibus elit.</div>
  <div id="subcontent">
    <img src="http://moviesalbum.com/wp-content/themes/sunny/timthumb.php?src=http://moviesalbum.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Koala-300x225.jpg&h=120&w=120&zc=1&q=90" width="50">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the html to be ordered as `<div id="text"/><div id="subcontent"/>` so that the text is rendered above the sub content when each is full width

Comment: @bts in this solution it does not matter. it will be rendered the same way

Comment: This is a better solution, in my opinion, since it doesn't rely on clearing divs that clutter up the markup (and thus are bad for accessibility)

Comment: It will also work right back to IE6 should anyone need it to. 
The only problem I see is that if the `text` div is smaller than the `subcontent` one, `wrapper` will not correctly wrap unless it is given a min-height

Answer (score 3):

Float is a pain.

Try to use flex and media queries for a responsive design :

**Note:** since you mention rtl reading, I strongly advise you to have a look on the flex-direction property ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction))

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  /* this is the default behavior - you can skip it */
  flex-direction: row;
}
#text {
}
#subcontent {
  width: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #wrapper {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In quis leo sapien. Nunc convallis elit purus, non fringilla quam lobortis at. Integer pharetra auctor luctus. In congue dolor a pretium facilisis. Donec et risus lacinia augue pellentesque mollis
    eget a urna. Sed dapibus est enim, id iaculis arcu ultrices sit amet. Donec quis dolor risus. Suspendisse a nunc a enim mattis finibus eget vitae diam. Phasellus dictum commodo metus, ut rutrum dolor pretium a. Aliquam at sem vel tortor mollis tristique.
    Proin neque dolor, pellentesque ut euismod id, finibus sed lacus. Mauris varius tempor diam, at varius risus. Etiam dictum metus et augue bibendum commodo. Vestibulum imperdiet elit vitae bibendum finibus. Maecenas mollis dui ex, id suscipit mauris
    cursus vitae. Vivamus nec faucibus elit.</div>
  <div id="subcontent">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/50/50/1" width="50">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated I still need to support IE9+ for this one (I know...)

Comment: Internet Explorer is also a pain haha. This answer may be useful to someone else anyway :)